# Sympy: lambdify such that operations on arrays always result in arrays, also for constants?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I need to evaluate the derivative of functions (f') given by the user in many points. The points are in a list (or numpy.array, pandas.Series...). I obtain the expected value when f' depends on a sympy variable, but not when f' is a constant:

```py
import sympy as sp

f1 = sp.sympify('1')
f2 = sp.sympify('t')

lamb1 = sp.lambdify('t',f1)
lamb2 = sp.lambdify('t',f2)

print(lamb1([1,2,3]))
print(lamb2([1,2,3]))
```

I obtain:

```
1
[1, 2, 3]
```

The second is alright, but I expected that the first would be a list of ones.

These functions are in a matrix and the end result of sympy operations, such as taking derivatives. The exact form of f1 and f2 varies per problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lamb1` is a function that returns the constant 1:  `def lamb1(x): return 1`.

`lamb2` is a function that returns its argument:  `def lamb2(x): return x`.

So, the output is very well the expected one.

Here is an approach that might work. I changed the test function for `f2` to `t*t` as that was more annoying in my tests (dealing with Pow(t,2)).

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

f1 = sp.sympify('1')
f2 = sp.sympify('t*t')

def np_lambdify(varname, func):
    lamb = sp.lambdify(varname, func, modules=['numpy'])
    if func.is_constant():
        return lambda t: np.full_like(t, lamb(t))
    else:
        return lambda t: lamb(np.array(t))

lamb1 = np_lambdify('t', f1)
lamb2 = np_lambdify('t', f2)

print(lamb1(1))
print(lamb1([1, 2, 3]))
print(lamb2(2))
print(lamb2([1, 2, 3]))
```

Outputs:

```
1
[1 1 1]
4
[1 4 9]
```

Comment: f1 and f2 are the derivative of a function that is given by the user like I said, the prurpose of using Sympy is to avoid that the user has to derivate and define functions. Also, the number of derivates depends on the problem, your solution is not the general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it isn't actually a problem for `lambdify` to return a constant, because NumPy's broadcasting semantics will automatically treat a constant as an array of that constant of the appropriate shape.

If it is a problem, you can use a wrapper like

```
def broadcast(fun):
    return lambda *x: numpy.broadcast_arrays(fun(*x), *x)[0]
```

(this is taken from https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5642, which has more discussion on this issue).

Note that using `broadcast` is better than `full_like` as in JohanC's answer, because broadcasted constant arrays do not actually take up more memory, whereas `full_like` will copy the constant in memory to make the array.

Answer (score 1):

With `isympy/ipython` introspection:

```
In [28]: lamb2??                                                                                 
Signature: lamb2(t)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(arg_0)

Expression:

t

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return (t)
```

and for the first:

```
In [29]: lamb1??                                                                                 
Signature: lamb1(t)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(arg_0)

Expression:

1

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return (1)
```

So one returns the input argument; the other returns just the constant, regardless of the input.  `lambdify` does a rather simple lexical translation from `sympy` to `numpy` Python.

## edit

Putting your functions in a `sp.Matrix`:

```
In [55]: lamb3 = lambdify('t',Matrix([f1,f2]))                                                   

In [56]: lamb3??                                                                                 
...
def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return (array([[1], [t]]))
...

In [57]: lamb3(np.arange(3))                                                                     
Out[57]: 
array([[1],
       [array([0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

So this returns a numpy array; but because of the mix of shapes the result is object dtype, not 2d.

We can see this with a direct array generation:

```
In [53]: np.array([[1],[1,2,3]])                                                                 
Out[53]: array([list([1]), list([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)

In [54]: np.array([np.ones(3,int),[1,2,3]])                                                      
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Neither `sympy` nor the `np.array` attempts to 'broadcast' that constant.  There are numpy constructs that will do that, such as multiplication and addition, but this simple sympy function and lambdify don't.

## edit

`frompyfunc` is a way of passing an array (or arrays) to a function that only works with scalar inputs.  While `lamb2` works with an array input, you aren't happy with the `lamb1` case, or presumably `lamb3`.

```
In [60]: np.frompyfunc(lamb1,1,1)([1,2,3])                                                       
Out[60]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=object)

In [61]: np.frompyfunc(lamb2,1,1)([1,2,3])                                                       
Out[61]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
```

This [61] is slower than simply `lamb2([1,2,3])` since it effectively iterates.

```
In [62]: np.frompyfunc(lamb3,1,1)([1,2,3])                                                       
Out[62]: 
array([array([[1],
       [1]]), array([[1],
       [2]]),
       array([[1],
       [3]])], dtype=object)
```

In this Matrix case the result is an array of arrays.  But since shapes match they can be combined into one array (in various ways):

```
In [66]: np.concatenate(_62, axis=1)                                                             
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: I understand what are you saying, thanks. However, in the script where I use it, as I mentioned, the two evaluations are made in a matrix (the functions are the gradient of another function). So when I evaluate, I obtain something like [1,[1,2,3]], but I need [[1,1,1],[1,2,3]], is there anyway for identify them and use someting like [1]*len([1,2,3]) to obtain the desired [1,1,1] in the case of lamb1?

Comment: `frompyfunc` might be useful.  It won't be fast, but for your general case it may be the cleanest solution.

Comment: Your solution is useful, but I prefer the solution of @JohanC (I don't know which is the best or the fastest)

Answer (score 0):

I often use the trick `t * 0 + 1` to create a zero-vector the same length as my input, but then add 1 to each of its elements. It works with NumPy; check if it works with Sympy!

Comment: f1 and f2 are calculated by sympy.diff (I omitted it in the question), I can't modificate them.

Comment: `sympy` simplifies `t * 0 + 1` to `1` - assuming `t` is a `sympy` symbol.  So using that to create `lamb1` won't make a change.  You'd have to apply that trick to the result of the `lamb1` function.

Answer (score 0):

I never use lambdify so I can't be too critical of how it is working. But it appears that you will need to fool it by giving it an expression that doesn't simplify to a scalar which, when evaluated with numbers *will* reduce to the desired value:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lambdify('t','(1+t)*t-t**2-t+42','numpy')(np.array([1,2,3]))
array([42, 42, 42])
```